# Get updated data from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, dictionary, plist

I have a plist in my app- settings plist.

I have 2 views.

First view with call button- I get phone number from appdelegate dictionary.
Second view I set phone number.
When I change phone number nothing no change. I need reload app for get changes.

This is my code:
Appdelegate:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
self.settingsDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

firstView:

```
self.app=(AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[self.app getDataFromPlist];
emergencyPhone=[self.app.settingsDic objectForKey:@"emergencyPhone"];
if (emergencyPhone.length==0) {
[btnEmergency setEnabled:NO];
btnEmergency.titleLabel.numberOfLines=3;
[btnEmergency setTitle:@" Not set " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

settingsView:

```
- (IBAction)btnSaveSettings:(id)sender {
[self.app.settingsDic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",etEmergencyPhone.text] forKey:@"emergencyPhone" ];
etEmergencyPhone.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;
[etEmergencyPhone setEnabled:NO];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
[self.app.settingsDic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[self.app getDataFromPlist];

}
```

Comment: I have a button to dial the phone user defines. When the phone is not set button does not work.
The problem, on the Settings If I delete a phone number then the button stops working - as it should. But after I make a phone number so the button does not return to work.
I have to shut down and restart software then I Independent Change

Answer (score 0):

```
self.app=(AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[self.app getDataFromPlist];
emergencyPhone=[self.app.settingsDic objectForKey:@"emergencyPhone"];
if (emergencyPhone.length==0) {
[btnEmergency setEnabled:NO];
 }
else{
[btnEmergency setEnabled:YES];
}
```